# erroe while compiling my own recipe in yocto (pyro)

Tags: linux, makefile, yocto, pyro

I am using pyro + ubuntu 16.04.
I have inherit externalsrc bb class and used EXTERALSRC for source directory.

I am getting an error while compiling my application.

**ERROR: "No rule to make target all"**

it is going to search Makefile on build directory.

i have given proper source tree path where the Makefile is available.

Comment: it always searching Makefile on Build path where the output file is there.

Comment: Could You show recipe configuration ? For _do_compile_ task You can check how bitbake setup all needed variables and resolve functions, this file are located in _${WORKDIR}/temp/log.do_taskname_, maybe this will help You figure out the problem. [docs](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#usingpoky-debugging-viewing-logs-from-failed-tasks)

Comment: In this new pyro version source code is copied from source directory to destination directory and even for my linux and u-boot but in my application it can not copy the source code.

Comment: To be clear, after fetching Your code in recipe _EXTERALSRC_ variable points to _${S}_, please check again correctly this file _${WORKDIR}/temp/run.do_compile_, maybe You need to set up _${S}_ variable. I'm think that You issue is just wrong path to source code.

Comment: i have checked source code path seems fine
see my bb file is like below 
S = source path
B = ${workdir}/build

EXTERNALSRC_pn-recipe-name = ${S}
EXTERNALSRC_BUILD-pn-recipe-name = ${B}

Comment: Another tip, You can run bitbake shell functions manually - in You case try to run this script file _${WORKDIR}/temp/run.do_compile_.

Comment: i am building source manually but still not getting any solution

Comment: it is an issue of tool chain. I have comment out into tool chain define into makefile.